# Where to search for jQuery plug-ins for specific functionality?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-plugins

Is there a jQuery plug-in clearing house or repository?  How do you find the functionality you are looking for?  My search in particular is to display events on a timeline and to do faceted searching, but I get no where from the clutter that is returned by my searches.

Answer (score 2):

The best place is good ol jQuery website: http://plugins.jquery.com/

There you'll find update, support, discussion, ratings, demos, etc. I don't know I'd trust plugins from other sources unless they're from some well-known site or blog.